# Extend Codeigniter config in hook

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to set additional configs defined in the database. My idea is to extend CI config in pre_controller hook.

The hook is not a problem, but how to extend CI config in the right way?

Can someone explain it to me with some example if possible?

Besides that, if I hook it in pre_controller, will it check configs and values from the database on every request with caching, because I need to check the table on every request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont need to use hooks necessarily

in application/core/ create your base application controller ex: AppController

```
class AppController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $config = $this->db->get('config')->result();

        foreach ($config as $config_item)
        {
            $this->config->set_item($config_item->name, $config_item->value);
        }
    }

}
```

and all your application controllers extends from AppController

```
class Main extends AppController
{
    // other functions
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, isn't it better to do it in some other way? in this way I have two extends...besides that, I have a lot of controllers to change because all of them extends CI_Controller...

Comment: In hooks add pre_system hooks and in hook file you can    $CI = &get_instance();        and     $CI->load->database();   $CI->database->get();    and $CI->load->{config_class} and $CI->config->set_item() ;  this is example!!!